EPWM1 and EPWM2 are not in sync TMS320F28379D
I am using LAUNCHXL-F2379D, I am creating sine wave of 50Hz using math function. positive half of that sinewave I am giving it to EPWM2 (working on 10kHz) whereas during negative half of the sine wave I am making EPWM2 zero (as shown in below fig named as S3). EPWM1 will create 50Hz PWM pulses with 50% duty cycle. such that EPWM1 will be high when EPWM2 is high. These need to bw in sync with each other as shown in fig below.
Output I want:

With following I was able to generate PWM pulses, but they are not in synced with each other there is 4.7ms to 5ms delay between these two pulse.
#include "F28x_Project.h"
#include "math.h"

#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#endif

__interrupt void cpu_timer0_isr(void);

void InitEPwm1Example(void);
void InitEPwm2Example(void);

float t = 0.0;
int compa;

void main(void){
    InitSysCtrl();

    CpuSysRegs.PCLKCR2.bit.EPWM1=1;
    CpuSysRegs.PCLKCR2.bit.EPWM2=1;

    InitEPwm1Gpio();
    InitEPwm2Gpio();

    DINT;

    InitPieCtrl();

    IER = 0x0000;
    IFR = 0x0000;

    InitPieVectTable();

    EALLOW;
    PieVectTable.TIMER0_INT = &cpu_timer0_isr;
    EDIS;

    InitCpuTimers();

    ConfigCpuTimer(&CpuTimer0, 200, 50);
    CpuTimer0Regs.TCR.all = 0x4000;

    EALLOW;
    CpuSysRegs.PCLKCR0.bit.TBCLKSYNC = 0;
    EDIS;

    InitEPwm1Example();
    InitEPwm2Example();

    EALLOW;
    CpuSysRegs.PCLKCR0.bit.TBCLKSYNC = 1;
    EDIS;

    IER |= M_INT1;

    PieCtrlRegs.PIEIER1.bit.INTx7 = 1;

    EINT;                               // Enable Global interrupt INTM
    ERTM;                               // Enable Global realtime interrupt DBGM

    while(1){
        // do nothing
    }
}

__interrupt void cpu_timer0_isr(void) {
    CpuTimer0.InterruptCount++;
    compa = 0.8*156*sin(2*M_PI*50*t);
    if(compa >= 0){
        EPwm2Regs.CMPA.bit.CMPA = compa;
    } else{
        EPwm2Regs.CMPA.bit.CMPA = 0;
    }
    EPwm1Regs.CMPA.bit.CMPA = 31250/2;    

    t = t + 0.00005;
    PieCtrlRegs.PIEACK.all = PIEACK_GROUP1;
}

void InitEPwm1Example(){
    EPwm1Regs.TBPRD = 31250;                                // Set timer period 801 TBCLKs
    EPwm1Regs.TBPHS.bit.TBPHS = 0x0000;                     // Phase is 0
    EPwm1Regs.TBCTR = 0x0000;                               // Clear counter

    EPwm1Regs.TBCTL.bit.CTRMODE = TB_COUNT_UPDOWN;          // Count up and down
    EPwm1Regs.TBCTL.bit.PHSEN = TB_DISABLE;                 // Master module
    EPwm1Regs.TBCTL.bit.SYNCOSEL = TB_CTR_ZERO;
    EPwm1Regs.TBCTL.bit.HSPCLKDIV = TB_DIV4;
    EPwm1Regs.TBCTL.bit.CLKDIV = TB_DIV4;

    EPwm1Regs.CMPA.bit.CMPA = 0;

    EPwm1Regs.CMPCTL.bit.SHDWAMODE = CC_SHADOW;
    EPwm1Regs.CMPCTL.bit.LOADAMODE = CC_CTR_ZERO;

    EPwm1Regs.AQCTLA.bit.CAU = AQ_CLEAR;
    EPwm1Regs.AQCTLA.bit.CAD = AQ_SET;
}

void InitEPwm2Example(){
    EPwm2Regs.TBPRD = 156;
    EPwm2Regs.TBCTR = 0x0000;

    EPwm2Regs.TBCTL.bit.CTRMODE = TB_COUNT_UPDOWN;
    EPwm2Regs.TBCTL.bit.PHSEN = TB_ENABLE;
    EPwm2Regs.TBPHS.bit.TBPHS = 0;
    EPwm2Regs.TBCTL.bit.SYNCOSEL = TB_SYNC_IN;
    EPwm2Regs.TBCTL.bit.PHSDIR = TB_UP;

    EPwm2Regs.TBCTL.bit.HSPCLKDIV = TB_DIV4;
    EPwm2Regs.TBCTL.bit.CLKDIV = TB_DIV4;

    EPwm2Regs.CMPA.bit.CMPA = 0;

    EPwm2Regs.CMPCTL.bit.SHDWAMODE = CC_SHADOW;
    EPwm2Regs.CMPCTL.bit.LOADAMODE = CC_CTR_ZERO;

    EPwm2Regs.AQCTLA.bit.CAU = AQ_CLEAR;
    EPwm2Regs.AQCTLA.bit.CAD = AQ_SET;
}

Actual Output I got:

Please let me know what mistakes I am making in code. Thank you in advance.

Did you take a look at the C2000Ware examples?

Yes i go through the examples but still it was showing the results.
